# Google Maps Place ID Finder - Can not highlight (copy) information on InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm using the Google Place ID as a way to link locations and other content in my database. So Basically I've created an admin page that allows me to set up a way to easily enter new locations and it's content.

On my admin page I've added a map using Place ID finder from Google so I can search for a place and in the InfoWindow highlight to copy the Place ID information, and then paste this information. For some reason the infowindow does not allow the highlight.

I thought it might be because the additional code from my admin page but [when I viewed the demo on Google developer documentation the demo also does not allow highlighting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eilBZ.png) If on the demo or my admin page I can click on another place on the map, [a new InfoWindow pops up and that information is highlightable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BANJL.png)

Can someone help using the code from documentation on Google Site (below), recode to allow the searched information window to be highlightable?

```
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .controls {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 29px;
        margin-left: 17px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        outline: none;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      .controls:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }
      .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }
      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="infowindow-content">
      <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
      Place ID <span id="place-id"></span><br>
      <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>

    <script>

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
          }

          // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
          marker.setPlace({
            placeId: place.place_id,
            location: place.geometry.location
          });
          marker.setVisible(true);

          infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
          infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
          infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent =
              place.formatted_address;
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Link to the example in the documentation (which demonstrates the issue): [Place ID Finder - Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infowindow-content has the CSS `user-select: none;` set (so the user can't select the text).  You can override that with:

```
#infowindow-content { 
  user-select: text !important; 
  -webkit-user-select: text !important;  /* for safari per Avrahm Kleinholz */
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/p42jz19d/)

- related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 11331: text inside InfoWindow cannot be selected](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11331)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This sample uses the Place Autocomplete widget to allow the user to search
// for and select a place. The sample then displays an info window containing
// the place ID and other information about the place that the user has
// selected.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }

    // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
    marker.setPlace({
      placeId: place.place_id,
      location: place.geometry.location
    });
    marker.setVisible(true);

    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-id'].textContent = place.place_id;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent =
      place.formatted_address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.controls {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}
.controls:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#infowindow-content {
  user-select: text !important
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span>
  <br>Place ID <span id="place-id"></span>
  <br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: I've run the snippet and also tried on my site but the content is still not selectable. I thought maybe the code was missing a semi-colon **;** too but that did not help either. Any other suggestions?

    `#infowindow-content {
      user-select: text !important;
     }`

Comment: Just to add, I Googled `user-select` and found that for Safari they require  `-webkit-user-select: text;` as `user-select` doesn't work with their bowser. So my code reads and it works perfectly! Thank you @geocodezip
`#infowindow-content {
  user-select: text !important;
  -webkit-user-select: text !important;
}`

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer to include the code for safari.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question with the help of geocodezip, I Googled `user-select` and found that for Safari they require `-webkit-user-select: text;` as `user-select` doesn't work with the Apple browser. So my code reads and it works perfectly!

```css
#infowindow-content { 
  user-select: text !important; 
  -webkit-user-select: text !important; 
}
```